# AccessLog does not exists?

Tags: logs, apache-httpd

I am a new user here and have problems with an Apache server:

[image]

error which I see first time on line 1016: 
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Just copy it and redact whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `CustomLog` directive, instead. From https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html -

> The server access log records all requests processed by the server.
>   The location and content of the access log are controlled by the
>   CustomLog directive. The LogFormat directive can be used to simplify
>   the selection of the contents of the logs. This section describes how
>   to configure the server to record information in the access log.